# WPF, why does my Binding only update from MainWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Why does `view.aBOX` only update `TextBoxA` from within `MainWindow`? and how to I fix that?

When I pass `view` to `w`, it runs perfectly fine. Even the debugger shows `view.aBOX` being updated with the message in `w`. However, it never updates `TextBoxA` from within `w`.

Example code:

```
//MAIN
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ViewModel view; //DEBUGGER SHOWS aBOX = "Worker STARTED", But no update
    Worker w; 

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.view = new ViewModel();
        this.DataContext = this.view;

        //TEST
        this.view.aBOX = "BINDING WORKS!!"; //UPDATES FINE HERE

        this.w = new Worker(this.view); 
    }
}

//VIEW
public class ViewModel
{
    public string aBOX { get; set; }
}

//WORKER
public class Worker
{
    ViewModel view;
    public Worker(ViewModel vm)
    {
        this.view = vm; 
        this.view.aBOX = "Worker STARTED"; //NEVER SEE THIS IN TextBoxA
    }
}

//XAML/WPF
<TextBox Name="TextBoxA" Text="{Binding Path=aBOX, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) for changes to be propagated to the binding engine.

If you are able to use a base class, you could use this:

```
public class Notify : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(Expression<Func<object>> exp)
    {
        string propertyName = ((exp.Body as UnaryExpression).Operand as MemberExpression).Member.Name;

        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Using it:

```
public int Property
{
  //getter
  set
  {
    property = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Property);
  }  
}
```

With this code, you can easily refactor the property and don't have to deal with magic strings. Also, you get intellisense.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! There wouldn't happen to be a auto-property change deal I could use? Pseudo example: `public string aBOX { get; set { OnPropertyChanged("aBOX"); } }`. The fix more than doubles my view code..

Comment: @PiZzL3 - Not yet, but you can [vote](http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/40583-wpf-feature-suggestions/suggestions/478802-modify-the-language-to-allow-for-observable-proper?ref=title) to have it added as a future feature.

Comment: Hmm.. there's some good info in the comments too... thanks again!

Comment: There are various other possibilities to get rid of all that boilerplate code, for example you could stick to an automatic property in your code and let 'Notify Property Weaver' generate the INotifyPropertyChanged-stuff for you. Alternatively you can use some base class or helper method, MVVM-frameworks give examples how to solve this.

Comment: I saw that in the comments and I want it bad... like ReSharper.. but sadly I can only afford to use C# Express right now (which doesn't support plugins/extensions/etc..). I'll look into those frameworks.

Comment: I've added an example on how I do it, I think that's something that will make your life much easier due to intellisense and refactoring capability.

Comment: Thanks, that's almost exactly what I did. Only thing that sucks is now my view model is north of 600+ lines instead of the ~100 before. I almost wrote a php script to parse it all out for me (which I think I'll still do to help in the future..).